# Number Array and user input

Tags: javascript

I need to write a code that will prompt the user for five integer numbers and then determine the product and sum of the values.

It needs to use an array to enter the values, use a for loop to display the numbers and product, a while loop to display numbers and their sum, and then an HTML line that will display "the sum of x y and z is: sum and the product of x y and z is: product". I have this so far, can anyone help me out?

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    s = 0,
    p = 1,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
  s += array[i];
  p *= array[i];
}
console.log('Sum : '+s + ' Product :  ' +p);
```

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is break your work up into two loops instead of one. What's the problem?

Comment: I guess im not sure how to do that as im more familiar with for loops, any ideas on how i would go about it? Also how would I add user inputs instead of the place holder 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Have you looked the [the documentation for a `while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)? Also, think about how you input information into a web page when you need to do it on someone else's page and then do some research on that. We are here to help, but we have guidelines for asking questions an d we expect that you'll do you research before posting.

Comment: Please be specific: What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using ECMAScript 6, here's one way to do this:

```js
let numbersToEnter = 5;
let numbersEntered = [];

while (numbersToEnter) {
  numbersEntered.push(parseInt(prompt(`Enter a number, ${numbersToEnter--} to go:`)));
}
// filter out non-numbers
numbersEntered = numbersEntered.filter(n => !isNaN(parseInt(n)));

const sum = numbersEntered.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
const product = numbersEntered.reduce((acc, val) => acc * val, 1);

console.log(`You entered these numbers: ${numbersEntered}`);
console.log(`Sum is ${sum}`);
console.log(`Product is ${product}`);
```